# static props evaluation resulting in exception

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am calling the below `SomeComponent` like following. `SomeComponent.render` is happening fine. But When i call `show` method I get `undefined is not an object 'arr[index].something'`

```
<SomeComponent arr={arr} />

export default class SomeComponent extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    arr: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,   
  };

  state = {
    x: 1, 
    x: 2,   
  };

  show(index) {
    const {arr} = this.props;
    if(arr[index].something){ // Here i get the issue. Seems likes arr is undefined.
    }   
  }

  render() {
    const {arr} = this.props;
    return(
      <Viewer images={arr} show={currentIndex => this.show(currentIndex)} />
    )   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show = (index) =>{
  const {arr} = this.props;
  if(arr[index].something){ // Here i get the issue. Seems likes arr is undefined.
  }   
 }
```

change this function to this way

```
   this.show = this.show.bind(this)
```

or add this line to constructor,(this.props) instance of component can't accessible in function without binding function

Comment: I do not have a constructor.

Comment: then use the 1st one ES6 arrow funtion